# biblatex-dw: footnote citations: add space-slash-space as multi name delimiters in footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{Hg\adddot}} ,
    editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space} 
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{ebert1989,
        year = {1989},
        title = {Räumt die Steine hinweg: DDR Herbst 1989: geistliche Reden im politischen Aufbruch},
        address = {München},
        publisher = {Claudius},
        isbn = {3532620987},
        editor = {Ebert, Andreas and Haberer, Johanna and Kraft, Friedrich},
        shorttitle = {Steine}
    }

    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {von Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{ebert1989} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have a special formatting which puts slashes with spaces between multi-author resources. However, it only puts slashes WITHOUT spaces in footnote citations, see images below. What do I need to add to also have spaces left and right of the slash in the footnote citation?

[image: spaces do not appear in footnote citations]
[image: spaces appear in bibliography]

Comment: Note that you don't need the redefinitions of `and={/},` and` page={},` with the other code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-dw` has `\bib...namedelim`s and `\cite..namedelim`s

```
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\citemultinamedelim}
```

You will need to redefine the `\cite...` delims as well.

With `biblatex-dw` you don't actually need to redefine `biblatex`'s `\multinamdelim`/`\finalnamdelim` as the definition of those commands is replaced by their `\cite...`/`\bib...` version depending on the context.